# Cropping layered PNG files with Ruby and MiniMagick

Tags: ruby, image, png, minimagick

I am using Ruby and MiniMagick to do some image manipulation.

I've added a drop shadow to a png, and I'm trying to crop off a side so that I can line it up with another image without the shadow overlapping with it in a very odd looking manner.

I've tried to use chop.  This works perfectly, except it will only chop off the left edge instead of the right.  I've tried changing the gravity, but this is fully ignored.

```
page1.gravity 'East'
page1.chop '8x0'
```

The code above chops 8 pixels off the left, even though everything I've found indicates it should be chopping 8 off the right.

I've tried to use crop.  Using just crop with a layered image returns no image at all.

I've tried to use crop and repage:

```
page1.crop '200x500+0+0'
page1.repage.+
```

This returns the following error:

```
/Users/elizabethday/.rbenv-usergems/2.0.0-p247/gems/mini_magick-3.6.0/lib/mini_magick.rb:409:in `run': Command ("mogrify -repage /var/folders/HH/HHJiNl08GyWfBCFvHn2R9++++TU/-Tmp-/jpg20131009-14809-1tjeck0") failed: {:status_code=>1, :output=>"mogrify: invalid argument for option `/var/folders/HH/HHJiNl08GyWfBCFvHn2R9++++TU/-Tmp-/jpg20131009-14809-1tjeck0': -repage @ error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageCommand/5558.\n"} (MiniMagick::Error)
    from /Users/elizabethday/.rbenv-usergems/2.0.0-p247/gems/mini_magick-3.6.0/lib/mini_magick.rb:363:in `combine_options'
    from /Users/elizabethday/.rbenv-usergems/2.0.0-p247/gems/mini_magick-3.6.0/lib/mini_magick.rb:342:in `method_missing'
    from menu_thumbnails.rb:114:in `<main>'
```

This error indicates that it's using the -repage option, when I specifically told it to use +repage.

I've tried flattening the png, but this just ends up as a black box.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this to work?

EDIT: Ok, I've discovered that, in general, gravity needs to be used in a combine_options block.

However, when using a combine_options block it still doesn't work properly.

The following block:

```
page1.combine_options do |c|
  c.gravity 'East'
  c.chop '8x0'
end
```

does absolutely no chopping of the image at all.  So I still seem to have made no progress in getting this image properly cropped.

Answer (score 0):

Put `repage.+` inside of your combine_options block as well. I've been having loads of the same type of issues you're having.

```
page1.combine_options do |c|
  c.repage.+
  c.gravity 'East'
  c.chop '8x0'
end
```